# What is the right way to look up EJB component?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

Have been trying to run my first EJB project for a couple of days so far. My EJB project currently has this source code:

```
package calc;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface SessionBeanRemote {
public int add(int a,int b);
}

package calc;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless(name="MySessionBean",mappedName="myCalculator")
public class SessionBean implements SessionBeanRemote {
public int add(int a,int b){
   return a +b;
}
}
```

Secondly, Have another simple java project where I can call EJB component :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.
SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
SessionBeanRemote bean =   (SessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("myCalculator");
int result = bean.add(3, 4);
System.out.println(result);
ctx.close();
```

JAR used : gf-client.jar, No need to add other JARs as Glassfish community commended

Exception caught :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.fsm.FSMImpl.(Lcom/sun/corba/ee/spi/orbutil/fsm/StateEngine;Lcom/sun/corba/ee/spi/orbutil/fsm/State;Z)V

2 other questions :

1. `context.lookup("java:global:/componentAddress")` vs `context.loopup("mappedName")` 
   what is the difference between them, when to use each ?
2. `props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.100")` vs.
      `props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost")`

Comment: There's quite a few discussions about this subject. You should be able to find your answer from: http://valery-lavrov.com/blog/2012/05/15/glassfish-3-ejb-3-1-and-standalone-client/

Comment: @SamiKorhonen I'm afraid, still get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Comment: And you are using appserv-rt.jar as instructed?

Comment: Yes sir, I have only added it as the link you provided says .

Comment: @SamiKorhonen It's a glassfish problem, downloaded latest version 3.1.2, and It worked without a hitch, thanks for your time sir.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're poking at CORBA? As a technology it's... very, very legacy. Also, it's probably easier to just have the appserver inject your beans using the `@EJB` annotation. Last, but not least, I have a nagging hunch that the home/remote interface nonsense is also no longer needed.

Comment: @millimoose Am at the first chapter of EJB3 in action book, Am looking at a lot of work studying EJB, I have no clue about EJB annotations & CORBA, because I've not studied EJB yet, I was only setting up the environment and all before I delve into the technology. I will take your notes down for now, and will turn to it when I needed it, thanks

Comment: Re: your "two other questions" bit: never ever do this. Don't move the goalposts on an existing question. If your original question, as asked, gets answered satisfactorily, an answer should be accepted and further questions about different problems should be separate posts.

Comment: I know rules on the stackoveflow, knocking myself out to go by the book, the 2 other questions regarding the original question after all, why should i start several questions in regard to the same matter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply problem came down to glassfish version 3.0, Downloaded the latest version 3.1.2 and everything works brilliant .

Comment: Please consider my answer, especially of `mappedName` which is **vendor-specific** while `@EJB(lookup="java:global/mycalculator-ejb/someBean!example.domain.project.SomeCalculatorRemote")` is portable, means is guaranteed to run all containers. If you later want to switch for whatever reason to an other container `mappedName` may **not** work (not guaranteed to be implemented). And never say never! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviewing and answering your questions now:

- Using `mappedName` is product-specific, means it is not guranteed to be working and containers are not obligated to implement it, but `name` in contrast is a must.
- you may wish to annotate it this way: `@Stateless(name="myCalculator", description="This EJB does some complex calculations.")` then you can use `Context.lookup()` in your code: `Context context = new InitialContext(); MyCalculatorRemote bean = (MyCalculatorRemote) context.lookup("java:global/mycalculator-ejb/myCalculator!example.domain.calculator.MyCalculatorRemote");`
- this example assumes that your project is named "mycalculator-ejb" following a recommended naming-convention, [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html) also shows you more details about this.
- sure you have to add some code here to make it actually working

Answer to 1): `java:global/project-ejb/someBean!example.domain.project.SomeRemote` is portable while the mapped name is not, means 1st works on any container and 2nd does maybe not. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html) at the official documentation.

Answer to 2): First is with IP saving you a DNS lookup, 2nd is with a hostname which is here the default value (`localhost`).

I hope this answers you some questions, even 4 years later.